# Hover effect on overlayed divs?

Tags: html, css

The problem I am currently having is that none of the buttons I create have the hover effect on them. This above is a small sample of the code I have. I am fairly sure this is due to the 100% width/height divs I've encased each button on, but I'm not fully sure how else to place them. This assumption also easily could be wrong.

```css
#testContainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.testButtonsDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.testButtons {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
    color: white;
}

#testButton1 {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
#testButton1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}

#testButton2 {
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
#testButton2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="testContainer">
    <div class="testButtonsDiv">
        <button id="testButton1" class="testButtons"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="testButtonsDiv">
        <button id="testButton2" class="testButtons"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your HTML you use the id `tailsButton2` while in the CSS you use `#testButton2`.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part when I tried to simplify the code down to post here, I've fixed it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the `.testButtonsDiv` of button 2 covering button 1. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My final goal is 9 buttons overlayed over an image in specific places, I've cut out all but 2 here to shorten the repetitive code. My goal is to have every button have that overlay effect, not just the one on top. I cannot figure out how to get each button to go to the location I want without enclosing each in its own div, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.testButtonsDiv` and position both buttons using `position: absolute`, `top`, and `left`:

```css
#testContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.testButtons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
  color: white;
}

#testButton1 {
  left: calc(50% - 35px);
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
}

#testButton1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}

#testButton2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 215px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
}

#testButton2:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="testContainer">
  <button id="testButton1" class="testButtons"></button>
  <button id="testButton2" class="testButtons"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. It seems I was overthinking it immensely. I think it was leftover thinking from a different way I tried. Thank you very much!